# Solution verification for this Fourier series problem

Tags: trigonometry, solution-verification, fourier-analysis, fourier-series, self-learning

I'm told to find the following signal as just a sum of **cosines**. The only Fourier coefficients that aren't zero are

[image]

Where $X[k]$ comes from $x(t) = \sum_{k = -\infty}^{\infty}X[k]e^{i \omega tk}$ and $j = \sqrt{-1} = i$.

My approach:
We want to find $x(t)$ as a sum of only cosines. We're told that the period is $T = 8$, so $\omega = \frac{\pi}{4}$

**I'm taking the $^{*}$ in $X^{*}[-3]$ to mean complex conjugate... (hopefully) ... please tell me if I'm wrong.
So $X[k = -3] = -4i$**

$$x(t) = X[k = -3]e^{i\frac{-3\pi}{4}t} + X[k = -1]e^{i\frac{-\pi}{4}t} + X[k = 1]e^{i\frac{\pi}{4}t} + X[k = 3]e^{i\frac{3\pi}{4}t}$$

Now substituting everything in

$$x(t) = -4ie^{i\frac{-3\pi}{4}t} + 2e^{i\frac{-\pi}{4}t} + 2e^{i\frac{\pi}{4}t} + 4ie^{i\frac{3\pi}{4}t}$$
$$x(t) = 4\cos(\frac{\pi}{4}t) + (4i)(e^{i\frac{3\pi}{4}t} - e^{i\frac{-3\pi}{4}t})$$
$$x(t) = 4\cos(\frac{\pi}{4}t) + (8i^2)(\sin(\frac{3\pi}{4}t))$$
$$x(t) = 4\cos(\frac{\pi}{4}t) - (8)(\cos(\frac{3\pi}{4}t + \frac{\pi}{2}))$$

However the answer is actually,

[image]

Does that mean I got the definition of $X^{*}[-3]$ wrong? What does it actually mean? If I don't take the complex conjugate of $4j$ then I have $8j\cos(\frac{3\pi}{4}t)$ which is also incorrect?

Comment: * can be used to denote [complex conjugate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_conjugate#Notation)

Comment: Oh, awesome! So I got that part right. I'm still wondering why I ended up with a negative that they didn't...?